# Imperatives with separable verbs

Tags: separable-verb, imperative

When forming the imperative of a separable verb, is the prefix sent to the end of the sentence (as in declarative sentences) or next to the verb?

---

I looked at the grammar exercise book *Practice Makes Perfect: German Verb Tenses*, chapter 8, and these web pages:

- [The Imperative (Command form) in German (Imperativ)](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/imperative)
- [The Imperative Mood](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/verbs/the-imperative-mood/).

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Did you check a grammar book before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your example sites show an example with a separable verb but neither is clear about these verbs being separable — and worse, germanforenglishspeakers.com even gives a wrong infinitive, completely clouding that the verb is, indeed, separable.

> Lies den Text vor!  ([Source](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/imperative))

The verb here is *vorlesen* (*to read out*). Note that the meaning would change if you used *lesen*: ‘Lies den Text!’, simply tells you to read, not to read out aloud.

---

> Nimm die Schlüssel mit. ([Source](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/verbs/the-imperative-mood/))

The verb here is **not** *nehmen* as the source claims. If it where, the meaning of the sentence would be ‘Take the keys.’ Rather, the verb is *mitnehmen* — ‘Take the keys **with you.’** Again, this is a separable verb and moves to the end of the sentence.

---

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Imper3.html) also has an example including a separable verb, but does not label it explicitly:

> Hören Sie auf. (*aufhören*)

---

The rule for this is that the imperative forms form a *Verbklammer* (verb bracket) just like the parts of a verb would in a normal (indicative) sentence. Typically, everything else is locate in the *Hauptfeld*, the bit between the two verb parts. Exceptions include infinitive constructions which, typically if longer, are often placed in the *Nachfeld*, i.e. after the second part. Examples:

> *Denk* darüber *nach*, mitzugehen.
>
> *Komm* morgen ins Kino *mit*.
>
> *Hör auf*, solchen Stuss zu erzählen.
>
> *Fang* endlich zu essen *an*. (Here the infinitive is short and can be pulled into the Hauptfeld. Arguably, this is not the most idiomatic way of saying this, though.)

Comment: The rule is that the prefix moves to the end (*rechte Satzklammer*). There are exceptions where movement is omitted, e.g. colloquial "Hau weg den Stoff!" ("Bottoms up!"), but they are quite rare and you might never encounter one.

Comment: @KilianFoth Thanks for reminding me to actually *write* about the rule rather than implying it ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer in Hammer's grammar. The prefix goes to the end, as in declarative sentences.